# Client/Server JVM_Bind exception

Tags: java, python, networking, client-server

I am trying to establish a SSL connection between **java server and python client.**

Here is the code:

> Server side:

```
public class s implements Runnable {


List<SSLSocket> socketList= new ArrayList<SSLSocket>();
List<File> FileList= new ArrayList<File>();
List<Certificate> CertificateList = new ArrayList<Certificate>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    s manager = new s();
    new Thread(manager).start();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true){
        System.out.printf("Send> ");
        String message = scanner.nextLine();
        if(message.equals("") || message.equals("/n")){
            continue;
        }else{
            manager.send(message);
        }
    }
}

private static SSLServerSocket getServerSocket(int thePort)
    {
        SSLServerSocket s=null;
        try
        {
            String key="G:\\mySrvKeystore";
        char keyStorePass[]="123456".toCharArray();

        char keyPassword[]="123456".toCharArray();
        KeyStore ks= KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

        ks.load(new FileInputStream(key),keyStorePass);


        KeyManagerFactory kmf= KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");

        kmf.init(ks,keyPassword);

        SSLContext sslContext= SSLContext.getInstance("SSLv3");

        sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(),null,null);


        SSLServerSocketFactory factory=sslContext.getServerSocketFactory();

        s=(SSLServerSocket)factory.createServerSocket(thePort);

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return(s);
}

public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            SSLServerSocket sslserversocket = getServerSocket(**9991**);
            SSLSocket  client = (SSLSocket)sslserversocket.accept();
            socketList.add(client);
            new Thread(new SSocket(client,socketList,FileList)).start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> Client side:

```
class timer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3)
        self.ssl_sock.connect(('localhost',9990))
        self.isrun = True
        threading.Thread.__init__(self);

def run(self): 
    while self.isrun:
        revice =  self.ssl_sock.recv(1024);
        print ("recv> " + revice); 
    self.sock.close();
    self.ssl_sock.close();

def send(self,str):
     self.ssl_sock.send(str + "\n")

def close(self):
    self.isrun=False

if __name__=='__main__':
     main()
```

I got:

[image]
I did not use reserve port and my OS is windows-7. And I run the server first then the client.

I don't understand why I cannot run multiple instance of the program?
Is it because I am using the same port?
But it was ok before when I just used socket instead of SSLsocket.

THanks for any help

Comment: Don't post screenshots of what is essentially just text. Copy/paste and format as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have multiple server processes listening to the same port.  How would the OS know which one gets the connection?

The usual way to handle multiple clients is to spawn a thread AFTER you have accepted a connection.  You pass the connection to the thread and the main thread loops, continuing to listen and accept new connections.

This is all very basic TCP/IP and has nothing to do with SSL.